# How is the intensity interpretation of Bohr's correspondence principle equivalent to the frequency interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, atomic-physics, equivalence-principle, photon-emission

The frequency interpretation of Bohr's correspondence principle seems obvious, given that a photon emitted after a dexcitation of an electron has to have the frequency that corresponds to the difference in energy levels.

However what about the intensity interpretation? It is explained as follows from some class notes:

> According to the *intensity interpretation*, the correspondence
> principle is defined as the agreement,  in the limit of
> large  quantum numbers, between probability, $P_{n'\to n''}$,
> of a transition between two stationary  states separated by
> $\tau$ and the square of the amplitude, $C_\tau$, of the
> $\tau$<sup>th</sup> harmonic component  of the classical motion:
> $$P_{n'\to n''} \propto |C_\tau(n)|^2 \quad\text{for large }n$$
> Thus in the limit large $n$ the amplitude of the harmonic
> components of the electron's classical orbit can be used
> to calculate the intensities of the spectral lines. While
> classically the intensity of radiation is determined by its
> amplitude, quantum mechanically the intensity of a spectral
> line is determined by how many photons are emitted at
> this particular frequency. Hence, the more probable a
> particular quantum transition is, the more photons will be
> given off, and the greater the intensity. Note that, as with
> the ftrquency interpretation, this is a correspondence that
> holds only statistically and only in the limit of large
> quantum numbers.

Thus, does the probability of a certain dexcitation happening increase if the energy change between levels is larger?

Isn't the energy of each photon considered in measuring intensity in QM?

And finally, if this intensity interpretation is just "statistical", then how is it equivalent to the frequency interpretation, which seems obvious?

Comment: are you asking about Kramers' "dispersion relations" doi.org/10.1038/113673a0 and doi.org/10.1038/114310b0 ?